# in an injection from A to B, do all elements from A have to be used?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

all the definitions I see of injection mention that each element from B is mapped to at most once by elements from A, but they do not mention whether all the elements from A must have some mapping to another element from B. In other words, if in the image attached (3) did not map to any element in Y, would this still be an injection?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hx0V.png)

Comment: If $f$ is _any_ function from $A$ to $B$, then (by the definition of a function) $f$ maps every element of $A$ to an element of $B$.

Comment: Just to make the point clear, an injection is a function (by definition of injection).

Comment: ohh right. So all functions defined as f: domain --> range will definitely map the whole domain to some subset of the range, right? And then from there it may be an injective, bijective, surjective.. etc. function?

Comment: @MichelleFan If $f: A \to B$ is only an injection then it's not necessary that all elements of $B$ have a preimage in $A$. It's only necessary that distinct elements in the image have distinct preimages, that is

$$f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y.$$

Surjectivity is the condition that every element of $B$ have a preimage in $A$, or equivalently, that the image of $f$ is all of $B$.

Comment: The reason that you didn't find the requirement "All elements of $A$ must have an image" in the definition of "injection" is that this requirement occurred earlier, in the definition of "function". The definition of "injection" does say that it has to be a function, and therefore all the requirements for functions apply in particular to injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most contexts, function are by their very nature assumed to be total, i.e. it is assumed that

$$\forall a \in A \ \exists b \in B \ f(a)=b$$

If this were not true, it would not be considered a 'function' in the first place. Indeed, a binary relation with this property is said to be *functional*, and if it lacks the property, it is *not* 'functional'.

That said, there are contexts (e.g. computability theory) where we want to talk about 'partial functions', for which this property does not hold (but we still regard it as a function ... just not a *total* function but a *partial* function).

So, the context should make it clear what is going on, though I would say that *injectivity* is merely:

$$\forall a_1 \in A \ \forall a_2 \in A \ (f(a_1) = f(a_2) \rightarrow a_1 = a_2)$$

so the property of being injective does not include or imply *totality* or *functionality* .. Again, *that* would be implied (in most contexts) by it being a function in the first place.

And so yes, if (3) would not map to anything, it would still be injective, but it may no longer be considered a function ... it would merely be a binary injective relation.

Answer (score 1):

$f:A\to B $ is injective $\iff $

1. $ \forall a\in A \;\;f (a) $ exists in B.
2. $\forall (a_1,a_2)\in A^2 $
   $$(f (a_1)=f (a_2)\implies a_1=a_2) $$

two different elements of A  must have two different images in B.